# Gradle Error while building a scala code

Tags: java, scala, ant, gradle, build.gradle

I am facing one issue with gradle while building scala code.

$gradle makeJar

Error : org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException :

Execution failed for task ':compileScala'.

Caused by : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1

$gradle -v

Gradle version - 1.6

groovy - 1.8.6

Ant - 1.8.4

ivy - 2.2.0

jvm - 1.7.0_55

OS - Linux 2.6x

## My build.gradle file is below -

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
apply plugin: 'scala'
def mypath = 'file://'+new File('test/lib').absolutePath
repositories {
flatDir dirs:"${mypath}"
}
configurations{
 scalaPackage
}
sourceSets{
 main{
  scala{
    srcDirs = ['test/src/scala']
  }
 }
}
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: mypath, includes: ['*.jar'])
  }
  task sourcePath{
    sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
  }
  task makeJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: compileScala){
    archivename = "mytest.jar"
    destinationDir = file("test/oplib")
    from "build/classes"
    classpath = configurations.scalaPackage
  }
  compileScala.dependsOn sourcePath
```

==========================================================

Here, my scala source code is present in - ./test/src/scala/test.scala

scala jar files present in - ./test/lib

expected output location - ./test/oplib

Is there anything wrong with build.gradle file which might be resulting in this error. Kindly suggest.

Many Thanks, Pralay

Answer (score 1):

If you use spark-core_2.11 Version 1.2.0 you can define your dependencies as following:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:1.2.0'
}
```

This dependency has Scala

```
org.scala-lang / scala-library / from 2.11.2 to 2.11.7
```

as a indirect dependency see

[Maven Repository Search for spark-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/1.2.0)

Comment: We have below jar for spark for CDH 5.3.2  - spark-assembly-1.2.0-cdh-5.3.2-<hadoop version>.jar. So, I tried with below line in dependency - compile 'org.apache.spark:soark-assembly:1.2.0-cdh5.3.2' ; but unfortunately gradle script unable to recognise this reference and throwing me error as "could not locate the dependency. I have kept this jar in my build path and I can able to run spark-shell or spark-submit which makes me think that spark assembly jar is properly referenced in build path.

Answer (score 0):

i take your `build.gradle` File and start it with a Gradle Wrapper with Gradle Version 2.3

first just with `gradlew`

Then i make 3 Corrections:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'
sourceCompatibility = '1.6'
def mypath = 'file://'+new File('test/lib').absolutePath
repositories {
flatDir dirs:"${mypath}"
}
configurations{
 scalaPackage
}
sourceSets{
 main{
  scala{
    srcDirs = ['test/src/scala']
  }
 }
}
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: mypath, includes: ['*.jar'])
  }
  task sourcePath{
    sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs
    sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []
  }
  task makeJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: compileScala){
    archiveName = "mytest.jar"
    destinationDir = file("test/oplib")
    from "build/classes"
    // classpath = configurations.scalaPackage
  }
  compileScala.dependsOn sourcePath
```

1. Move the Line `sourceCompatibility` after the Scala Plugin Import
2. Write `archiveName` instaed of `archivename`
3. Comment out `classpath`

Then i run `gradlew tasks` and `gradlew makeJar` without Error.

Comment: I tried with the changes you proposed but it is resulting in same error as before in Gradle 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Scala projects need to declare a scala-library dependency.
Add this in your build.gralde File:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.1'
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried with the above option. But it's still failing with same error. I am guessing that in my case, scala is with spark(version 1.2.0) package. I have tried to set SCALA_HOME to spark home but it didn't work as well.